# Telebot: как получить айди телеграм канала при добавлении бота в группу?

Tags: python, telebot, handlers

уже долгое время ищу информацию про обработчик добавления телеграмм бота в канал. Требуется при добавлении бота в канал (публичный и частный) программно сохранять его айди и название, используя библиотеку telebot